# List of list of Floats to Decimals in Python using zip

Tags: python, decimal, python-zip

I'm trying to convert a list of list of Floats into a list of list of Decimals in a zip function to create a dictionary. I cannot use a for loop for performance issues as this is a very long list of list of floats:

```py
# The following data is just an example, not real data.
keys = ['a','b','c']
values = [[1.2342,-3.32,5.4322],[-4.32,7.542,9.76],[6.54,0.98,-1.22]]

# The following line outputs a dictionary where each key has a list of floats as value.
# I need those floats to be instead Decimal as I need to save them on a Dynamodb
# instance which does not support floats.

dictionary_of_floats = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

The following solution uses a for loop which in my case results in a killed session as the data is to big:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

dict_of_decimals = {}
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    dict_of_decimals[key] = [Decimal(str(x)) for x in values[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could think of without directly using for loop:

```
dictionary_of_floats = dict(zip(keys, [[Decimal(dec) for dec in value] for value in values]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
values = [[1.2342,-3.32,5.4322],[-4.32,7.542,9.76],[6.54,0.98,-1.22]]

def _decimal(i):
    return Decimal(str(i))

dict_of_decimals = {}
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    dict_of_decimals[key] = list(map(_decimal, values[i]))
```

if you don't want to use enumerate you can do something like, but I honestly don't know why you would want something like this

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
values = [[1.2342,-3.32,5.4322],[-4.32,7.542,9.76],[6.54,0.98,-1.22]]

def _decimal(i):
    return Decimal(str(i))

def decimal_list(l):
    return list(map(_decimal, l))

values = list(map(decimal_list, values))
dict_of_decimals = zip(keys, values)
```